# How to use onSnapshot in firebase? Can't work in my apps

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have made my own web apps(using vue.js) and using firestore as backend.
In my firebase method, I tried to use onSnapshot method in firestore,
but result was undefined.

firebase version is latest(v9).

so my code is below.

```
let user;
    const snapshot = await onSnapshot(collection(db, "user"), (snap: any) => {
      let user: any = [];
      snap.docs.forEach((doc: any) => {
        user.push({ ...doc.data() });
      });
      return user;
    });
    snapshot();
    console.log(user);
```

My firestore data is symple like below.

```
collection: user
documet: uid(automatically made by firebase)
data:{
 name:'someone name',
 age:22
}
```

so I was expected the result like that

```
{
 name:'someone name',
 age:22
}
```

but result was 'undefined'
Does anyone give me advise, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onSnapshot` function doesn't return a `Promise`, so you can't use `await` on it. What you're looking for is `getDoc`:

```
const snap = await getDocs(collection(db, "user"));
let user: any = [];
snap.docs.forEach((doc: any) => {
  user.push({ ...doc.data() });
});
console.log(user);
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting a document once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

Comment: `getDocs()` for a CollectionReference :)

Comment: @Dharmaraj Darn. I checked twice, specifically for that, and still missed it!    I really shouldn't be answering v9 questions after a long FireConf day.    Thanks for the save. 

Comment: Reason I used snapshot, I wanted to get realtime updates through that method. If I use getDocs methods instead, is that method possible to get realtime data? or I have to call that function when firestore database change.

Comment: You can't use `await` with a stream, since `await` only *waits* for once value. You can't wait for a stream; after all - when would it be done? If you want to use `onSnapshot` any code that needs the data from the database needs to be inside the `onSnapshot` callback, or be called from there. A `return` inside the callback will not work.